# How to define, append or map objectID to an array for Algolia?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, algolia

In the docs, there is no example to explicitly define ObjectID. I do not want to use  `autoGenerateObjectIDIfNotExist` as it duplicates my objects in the index. Nor do I want to use `replaceAllObjects` as creates more and more Indices each time.

I am using `useEffect` to pull the API from MongoDB. How would I define ObjectID by appending a custom ObjectID? Through a`for` loop?

For reference, this is for a MERN app.

If an ObjectID is not defined this error pops up:

> "All objects must have an unique objectID (like a primary key) to be
> valid. Algolia is also able to generate objectIDs automatically but
> *it's not recommended*. To do it, use the `{'autoGenerateObjectIDIfNotExist': true}` option."

```
useEffect(() => {

    const config = {

      headers: {

        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,

      },

    };

    const fetchPasswords = async () => {

      const { data } = await axios.get("/api/passwords", config);

      setPasswords(data);

    };

    fetchPasswords();

  }, []);
```

```
index

    .saveObjects(passwords, {

      objectIDs: passwords._id,

    })

    .then(({ objectIDs }) => {

      console.log(objectIDs);

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you get back the `data`. you can run a `forEach` through the array and replace the `_id` field with `objectID` field. After that `setPasswords(data)`
For an example like this

```js
const data = [
{
_id: 1,
password: 'password1'
},{
_id: 2,
password: 'password2'
},{
_id: 3,
password: 'password3'
}
]

data.forEach((password) => {
  password.objectID = password._id;
  delete password._id;
})

console.log(data);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```js
      const { data } = await axios.get("/api/passwords", config);
      //run the forEach for data.....
      setPasswords(data);
```

Now that each record has an `objectID` you can index your data the usual way like

```js
index.saveObjects(passwords).then(({ objectIDs }) => {
  console.log(objectIDs);
});
```

You can do this like or you can set the `objectID` from the backend itself and send to frontend.

Comment: you saved me a lot of pain, that did the trick. I could use redux, but I do not want the headache right now